# What does return function do in the functions below?

Tags: python-3.x, function, return-type

Can you please explain to me what the `return` functions for `call` and `squared_call` do?

```
def mult_by_five(x):
    return 5 * x

def call(fn, arg):
    """Call fn on arg"""
    return fn(arg)

def squared_call(fn, arg):
    """Call fn on the result of calling fn on arg"""
    return fn(fn(arg))

print(
    call(mult_by_five, 1),
    squared_call(mult_by_five, 1), 
    sep='\n', # '\n' is the newline character - it starts a new line
)
```

Comment: My understanding of it is that it passes the value of an operation or a variable when the function is called. What i am asking is what the multiple brackets after the return function does in the call and squared_call functions.

Comment: The `()` calls a function. E.g. `return fn(arg)` returns the return value of calling `fn` with `arg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a step back and substitute in different functions, this will make more sense.

Instead of `return fn(fn(n))`, look at simpler examples.

```
return int(n)
```

This returns the result of `int(n)`. `n` is passed to `int`, then whatever `int` returns is returned.

```
return str(int(n))
```

This returns the result of `str(int(n))`. `n` is passed to `int`, then whatever `int` returns is passed to `str`, then whatever `str` returns is returned.

The difficult part in that example is that `fn` are functions that were passed in as arguments to `call` and `squared_call`.

When you write `call(mult_by_five, 1)`, the return line in `call` is equivalent to:

```
return mult_by_five(1)
```

When you write `squared_call(mult_by_five, 1)`, the return line in `squared_call` is equivalent to:

```
return mult_by_five(mult_by_five(1))
```

Comment: This makes more sense now. Thank you very much.